# Error creating grouped sub-lists from a given list sizes when the sub-lists of the list sizes are similar

Tags: python, list, sorting, grouping

I am new to Programming and started learning Python recently. I really appreciate your help regarding this issue!

I have a list of two sub-lists containing two items in each. I also have another list called Parts that dictates the segregation of those items. While the below codes seem to work properly, but don't do the job right when the sublists of the Parts(partition sizes) list are the same/identical.
Need some expert help or advice.

*Note: The sum of int in the Parts sublist is equal to the length of the corresponding Items sublist.*

[Screenshot of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0qmr.png)

Written Code is below:

```
Items = [["A","B"],["C","D"]]
Parts = [[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0]] #the sublists are identical. Cause of error for this script

List = []
for i in Parts:
    Temp = []
    A = 0
    for j in i:
        if j == 0:
            x = []
        else:
            x = Items[Parts.index(i)][int(A):int(A+j)]
            A = j
        Temp.append(x)
    List.append(Temp)

Print(List)
```

Just to make it clear, I am stating my inputs and outputs (Current and expected) below.

**Scenario 01: NO ERROR**

*Inputs:*

Items = `[["A","B"],["C","D"]]`

Parts = `[[0,0,2,0],[1,1,0,0]]`

*Output:*

Current Output *(as expected)*= `[ [ [],[],["A", "B"],[] ] , [ ["C"],["D"],[],[] ] ]`

**Scenario 02: ERROR**

*Inputs:*

Items = `[["A","B"],["C","D"]]`

Parts = `[[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]`

*Output:*

Current Output= `[ [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ] , [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ] ]`

Expected Output = `[ [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ] , [ ["C"],["D"],[],[] ] ]`

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Comment: ```[int(A):int(A+j)]``` you're trying to convert letters to integers ?

Comment: `if j == 0: ... else:` This let the index zero not handled. I mean `Parts.index[0]` or `Temp.append(0)` won't never occur. Is it what you expect ?  Otherwise you should remove the else.

Comment: @coderoftheday Could you check the image attached? Maybe that helps in terms of understanding what I meant. Please let me know if that's still vague, I can elaborate on the text further and the outputs.

Comment: @coderoftheday Apologies! I interchanged the input data by mistake while writing the question. Have now edited it right, Please check the code again. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @dspr Apologies! I interchanged the input data by mistake while writing the question. Have now edited it right, Please check the code again. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I am stating my inputs and outputs (Current and expected) below.
Inputs:
    Items = [["A","B"],["C","D"]]
    Parts = [[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]
Output:
    Current Output= [ [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ] , [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ] ]
    Expected Output = [ [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ] , [ ["C"],["D"],[],[] ] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an answer from another platform, [Dynamo BIM Forum](https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/partitioning-items-into-sub-lists-based-on-list-lengths-custom-python-code/57363/3)

[@AmolShah](https://forum.dynamobim.com/u/AmolShah) suggested two solutions:

**Solution 01:** *By introducing another variable*

```
Items = [["A","B"],["C","D"]]
Parts = [[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0]] #the sublists are identical. Cause of error for this script

List = []
B = 0

for i in Parts:
    Temp = []
    A = 0
    for j in i:
        if j == 0:
            x = []
        else:
            x = Items[B][int(A):int(A+j)]
            A = j
        Temp.append(x)
    List.append(Temp)
    B += 1

Print(List)
```

**Solution 02:** *Altering the code without adding new variables.*

```
Items = [["A","B"],["C","D"]]
Parts = [[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0]] #the sublists are identical. Cause of error for this script

List = []

for i in range(len(Parts)):
    Temp = []
    A = 0
    for j in Parts[i]:
        if j == 0:
            x = []
        else:
            x = Items[i][int(A):int(A+j)]
            A = j
        Temp.append(x)
    List.append(Temp)

Print(List)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Items = [["A","B"],["C","D"]]
Parts = [[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]

new_list = []

for item,part in zip(Items,Parts):
    temp_l =[]
    for n,x in enumerate(part):
        if x != 0:
            temp_l.append(item)
        else:
            temp_l.append([])
    new_list.append(temp_l)
    temp_l=[]

print(new_list)

>>> [[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], [], []], [['C', 'D'], ['C', 'D'], [], []]]
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot; appreciate it!!

Comment: But, I was looking to get: [ [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ] , [ ["C"],["D"],[],[] ] ] as solution.

Comment: I am trying get the solution this way [   [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ]   ,   [ ["C"],["D"],[],[] ]   ]

Comment: It still is giving [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], [], [], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'D'], [], []] instead of [ [ ["A"],["B"],[],[] ] , [ ["C"],["D"],[],[] ] ]  :|

Comment: @KiranGolla I've edited my answer, it should give you your desired output